Docker File COPY command not working for src parameter
Have the following Docker file that build with command (sudo docker build --no-cache -t hcorte/bakcup_container .)
Docker File:
FROM ubuntu:20.04
FROM postgres:17.0

COPY backup.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY ~/.pgpass ~/.pgpass
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod u+x backup.sh

#debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y bash \
&& apt-get install -y cron \
&& apt-get install -y iputils-ping
#RUN sudo apt install postgresql

CMD [“/bin/bash”] 
#RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls /usr/local/bin/'

but return the following error
   3 |     
   4 |     COPY backup.sh /usr/local/bin/
   5 | >>> COPY home/username/.pgpass ~/.pgpass
   6 |     WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/
   7 |     RUN chmod u+x backup.sh

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref a7651d8c-dfb4-495e-8b72-5cda0bffc97b::lxiavo5lh18oq8s5ogx0o5g3z: "/home/username/.pgpass": not found

but in my host machine that file exists in that path and in the first copy works as expected so does it have to do being a hidden file?

The first argument to the COPY command is relative to the build context, not your host filesystem root. https://docs.docker.com/build/concepts/context/

ok thanks @SimonCrowe gona try chaging to relative path of build

According to the docs "[w]hen you specify a local directory or a tarball, all subdirectories are included", this means that you would need to set the build context to /home/username/.

(Copying any sort of credential into the image usually isn't a best practice: anyone who gets a copy of the image can docker run the-image cat .pgpass and get your database credentials back out.)

ok so its best if manually create in the docker image directly, was doing that before but thought it would be better to automatize that, thanks for the feedback.
